# centre a fluid nav with varying list item width

Tags: css, fluid-layout

how can i centre the list items in the nav bar, list items are of varying width?
 thanks

```
<div class="wrapper" style="width:100%">
<div class="nav" style="width:100%">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PROJECTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">TOURS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">VOLUNTEER</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

> > .nav ul{text-align:center;}

if that doesn't work, try

> > .nav ul {width:100%; overflow:hidden;}
> >     .nav ul li{position:relative;margin:0px auto;}

Answer (score 2):

Try **this**:

```
.nav ul {text-align: center;}
.nav ul li {display: inline-block; *display: inline; *zoom: 1; border: 1px solid #999; background: #ccc; padding: 5px;}​​
.nav ul li a {text-decoration: none;}
```

You had given a `</nav>`, which is actually `</div>`. The corrected **HTML**:

```
<div class="wrapper" style="width:100%">
    <div class="nav" style="width:100%">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">PROJECTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">TOURS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">VOLUNTEER</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>​
```

Hope this helps. Check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sfYnm/)! :)